# How to Read contents of a file and write that content to another file in C# WPF

Tags: filestream, streamwriter

I am creating a WPF application where I want to read contents of a file and write it to another file.

Comment: SO is not the place for "provide me code to use"

Comment: Yes, kindly provide me the code to use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is not asking any questions. He just wants someone to code for him.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File` under `System.IO`... Here is an example:

```
string path1 = "main file path here";
string path2 = "second file path here";
string contents = File.ReadAllText(path1);
File.WriteAllText(path2, contents);
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite if the target already exists:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile, true);
```

If not:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile);
```